# Introducing WebAPI in ASP.NET MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an MVC4 application that uses MVC controllers and it is already in production. But a new requirement is to expose some of the functionality as a web service so it is accessible to get/post data programatically by other applications. So I am thinking of introuding WebAPI in this application and use it to provide an iterface to external world as well as use the same service by the views in my application.

My question is how can I use WebAPI in my existing controllers so that I can return Views instead of raw Json data.

Thanks

Comment: Why re-engineer WebAPI into something that MVC already does well? Let your MVC controllers handle html views and WebAPI controllers return JSON or XML.

Comment: Hi Jasen, Thanks for your comments. But then I will be duplicating the same logic in both controllers which I don't think I should have to do.

Comment: Couldn't that logic be moved into a common service both controllers use? In that way your MVC controller only selects the appropriate view and relies on this _service_ to perform business logic. The WebAPI controller uses the same _service_ and returns the data collection as JSON.